# Babel support explorer 11

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

My goal is to use ES6+, And still support Explorer 11.

I understand Babel provides the answer to purpose.

On the official website of Babel: [https://babeljs.io/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vom9Y.jpg)

I wrote an example:

[image]

I would expect the output of Babel will be :

```
var a = 5;
```

what am I missing?

Thank you all!

Comment: supporting ie11 is a configuration option. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env -- search on that page for `"ie": "11"`

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 supports `let` (albeit with some bugs when used in for loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel by default uses browserslist with no polyfills. Those you will need to configure manually. If you want to toy around online, try using https://babeljs.io/repl, and make sure to enable everything according to your needs in the left sidebar.